# Unable to install Python pip or use easy_install

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I am on OSX 10.10.3 with Python 2.7.6 as my main Python. I suddenly ran into trouble using pip, and tried to fix it. The solution proposed elsewhere on StackOverflow was to remove installations of pip and reinstall it either using their official installer or using easy_install.

Running the installation script (https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pip.py", line 17767, in <module>
    main()
  File "pip.py", line 162, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "/tmp/tmpDnRtQK/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/optparse.py", line 90, in <module>
    from gettext import gettext
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 49, in <module>
    import locale, copy, os, re, struct, sys
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 110, in <module>
    @functools.wraps(_localeconv)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wraps'
```

and running "sudo easy_install pip" gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.7", line 7, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2793, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 673, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 581, in resolve
    requirements.extend(dist.requires(req.extras)[::-1])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2323, in requires
    dm = self._dep_map
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2374, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: _dep_map
```

I am not really sure where to go next.

I am also in the situation that I can't import various modules, for example Flask, since I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dawi/git/friends/run.py", line 2, in <module>
    from application import app
  File "/Users/dawi/git/friends/application/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.9.6-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 154, in <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.9.6-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
    from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Werkzeug-0.9.6-py2.7.egg/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 23, in <module>
    from functools import update_wrapper
ImportError: cannot import name update_wrapper
```

Comment: How did you remove the previous installation of pip and where was it located? Are you sure there are not multiple directories with pip installations?

Comment: I removed the folders. I am not entirely sure where they were located. I could find two folders. I have not been able to locate anymore pip installations, but I might be missing something.

Comment: With the references to /Library and /System/Library in your tracebacks, it looks like you're working with the Apple-supplied python. I have found it easier and more fruitful to install and use my own python using homebrew or spack (https://github.com/LLNL/spack).